Differences/Similarities Between そうすると and そうしたら
Just learned the grammar point そうすると and was wondering is そうしたら is the same thing.
For example, would
早く大学を卒業したいです。そうすると、仕事ができる be the same as 早く大学を卒業したいです。そうしたら、仕事ができる？

Probably not enough for a separate answer, but I would say that そうすると is basically equivalent to そ[う]して, which would then differ from そうしたら in more or less the same way. I would use そうしたら for your example, as the prospect of 早く卒業する doesn't seem at all certain in the hypothetical. (But if you're actually in that situation, 頑張ってくださいね.)

「そうすれば」もありますよね。「早く卒業したいです。そうすれば、働けますから。」

It is more or less the difference between と and たら. You can look at the following, for example:

Differences among -たら, なら, -と, -んだったら, -ば, etc
What is the difference between と, たら and 時【とき】?

A simplistic answer based on this site is,

use そうしたら if you are not sure because it is more often used,
そうすると is commonly used for something that always happens in sequence (like in teaching directions or steps).

Regarding the second point, for example

ここをクリックします。そうすると選択画面が現れます Click here. Then, a dialog showing options will appear.

Here そうしたら is possible, too, but そうすると should be more common. Also note there seems a regional difference which is more common, mentioned in the first link above.
As for your example, it is a one-off individual event, so そうしたら is more natural. (A side point is, if you mean I can work, 働ける would be better than 仕事ができる.)

I came across a research article exactly about the difference between the two. So, an unfriendly advice is, if you 'just learned' them, you shouldn't really care.
